# Laravel unit testing emails

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

My system sends a couple of important emails.  What is the best way to unit test that?

I see you can put it in pretend mode and it goes in the log. Is there something to check that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two options.

Option 1 - Mock the mail facade to test the mail is being sent. Something like this would work:

```
$mock = Mockery::mock('Swift_Mailer');
$this->app['mailer']->setSwiftMailer($mock);
$mock->shouldReceive('send')->once()
    ->andReturnUsing(function($msg) {
        $this->assertEquals('My subject', $msg->getSubject());
        $this->assertEquals('foo@bar.com', $msg->getTo());
        $this->assertContains('Some string', $msg->getBody());
    });
```

Option 2 is much easier - it is to test the actual SMTP using [MailCatcher.me](http://mailcatcher.me/). Basically you can send SMTP emails, and 'test' the email that is *actually* sent. [Laracasts has a great lesson on how to use it as part of your Laravel testing here](https://laracasts.com/lessons/testing-email-in-laravel).

Comment: Do I need to do something for the asserts to run?  Because I have a method that just runs a Mail::send().  If I call is after this I don't have the asserts going up.

Comment: So I found that pretend was causing it to not work.  So I had to turn that off.  Thanks @the-shift-exchange

Comment: BadMethodCallException: Method Mockery_0_Swift_Mailer::getTransport() does not exist on this mock object

Comment: Method send() from Mockery_0_Swift_Mailer should be called
 exactly 1 times but called 0 times.

Answer (score 6):

"Option 1" from "@The Shift Exchange" is not working in Laravel 5.1, so here is modified version using Proxied Partial Mock:

```
$mock = \Mockery::mock($this->app['mailer']->getSwiftMailer());
$this->app['mailer']->setSwiftMailer($mock);
$mock
    ->shouldReceive('send')
    ->withArgs([\Mockery::on(function($message)
    {
        $this->assertEquals('My subject', $message->getSubject());
        $this->assertSame(['foo@bar.com' => null], $message->getTo());
        $this->assertContains('Some string', $message->getBody());
        return true;
    }), \Mockery::any()])
    ->once();
```

Comment: Works for Laravel 5.2 as well (Y)

Answer (score 6):

For Laravel 5.4 check `Mail::fake()`:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mocking#mail-fake

Comment: It does not test it there is a problem inside email. Mailable->build() is never executed and email- blade is never build.

Answer (score 3):

If you just don't want the e-mails be really send, you can turn off them using the "Mail::pretend(true)"

```
class TestCase extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase {
    private function prepareForTests() {
      // e-mail will look like will be send but it is just pretending
      Mail::pretend(true);
      // if you want to test the routes
      Route::enableFilters();
    }
}

class MyTest extends TestCase {
    public function testEmail() {
      // be happy
    }
}
```

Comment: That OK for setting up, but then how do you test from there?

Comment: The way that I deal with that: During my tests, instead of sending e-mail, saving them in a temporary folder as files. I don't think you should send an e-mail every time that you run a test. But, it is good to have the content of e-mail saved in a place where you can check. Another tip is to add to in the file the headers of the e-mail, from foo@bar.com to bob@bob.com Subject "Hello World", etc.

Comment: I ended up setting up mine with a mailcatch in docker. Took a long time

Answer (score 2):

If any one is using docker as there development environment I end up solving this by:

## Setup

`.env`

```
...
MAIL_FROM       = noreply@example.com

MAIL_DRIVER     = smtp
MAIL_HOST       = mail
EMAIL_PORT      = 1025
MAIL_URL_PORT   = 1080
MAIL_USERNAME   = null
MAIL_PASSWORD   = null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION = null
```

`config/mail.php`

```
# update ...

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

# to ...

'port' => env('EMAIL_PORT', 587),
```

*(I had a conflict with this environment variable for some reason)*

Carrying on...

`docker-compose.ymal`

```
mail:
    image: schickling/mailcatcher
    ports:
        - 1080:1080
```

`app/Http/Controllers/SomeController.php`

```
use App\Mail\SomeMail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;


class SomeController extends BaseController
{
    ...
    public function getSomething(Request $request)
    {
        ...
        Mail::to('someone@example.com')->send(new SomeMail('Body of the email'));
        ...
    }
```

`app/Mail/SomeMail.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SomeMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $body;

    public function __construct($body = 'Default message')
    {
        $this->body = $body;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this
            ->from(ENV('MAIL_FROM'))
            ->subject('Some Subject')
            ->view('mail.someMail');
    }
}
```

`resources/views/mail/SomeMail.blade.php`

```
<h1>{{ $body }}</h1>
```

## Testing

`tests\Feature\EmailTest.php`

```
use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\SomeController;

class EmailTest extends TestCase
{
    privete $someController;
    private $requestMock;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->someController = new SomeController();
        $this->requestMock = \Mockery::mock(Request::class);
    }

    public function testEmailGetsSentSuccess()
    {
        $this->deleteAllEmailMessages();

        $emails = app()->make('swift.transport')->driver()->messages();
        $this->assertEmpty($emails);

        $response = $this->someController->getSomething($this->requestMock);

        $emails = app()->make('swift.transport')->driver()->messages();
        $this->assertNotEmpty($emails);

        $this->assertContains('Some Subject', $emails[0]->getSubject());
        $this->assertEquals('someone@example.com', array_keys($emails[0]->getTo())[0]);
    }

    ...

    private function deleteAllEmailMessages()
    {
        $mailcatcher = new Client(['base_uri' => config('mailtester.url')]);
        $mailcatcher->delete('/messages');
    }
}
```

*(This has been copied and edited from my own code so might not work first time)*

(source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52177526/563247)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test everything around the email, use

```
Mail::fake()
```

But if you want to test your `Illuminate\Mail\Mailable` and the `blade`, then follow this example. Say, you want to test a Reminder email about some payment, where the email text should have product called 'valorant' and some price in 'USD'.

```
 public function test_PaymentReminder(): void
{
    /* @var $payment SalePayment */
    $payment = factory(SalePayment::class)->create();
    auth()->logout();

    $paymentReminder = new PaymentReminder($payment);
    $html            = $paymentReminder->render();

    $this->assertTrue(strpos($html, 'valorant') !== false);
    $this->assertTrue(strpos($html, 'USD') !== false);
}
```

The important part here is `->render()` - that is how you make `Illuminate\Mail\Mailable` to run `build()` function and process the `blade`.

Another importan thing is `auth()->logout();` - because normally emails being processed in a queue that run in a background environment. This environment has no user and has no request with no URL and no IP...

So you must be sure that you are rendering the email in your unit test in a similar environment as in production.

Answer (score 0):

I think that inspecting the log is not the good way to go.

You may want to take a look at how you can mock the Mail facade and check that it receives a call with some parameters.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using [Notifcations](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/notifications) in laravel you can do that like below

```
Notification::fake();
$this->post(...);
$user = User::first();
Notification::assertSentTo([$user], VerifyEmail::class);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mocking#notification-fake