# Testing event send email in Laravel

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I am creating a RESTFUL API for forgot password feature in my Laravel project. I finished it.

However, I don't know how to build unittest to testing event send email occurred?

How do I build it?

Comment: This is a good question but would be enhanced if you could post any code. You generally wouldn't write a unit test that an email was sent (do you want your unit tests to start emailing?) but verifying that a request to send an email was correctly raise with the correct body/subject etc might be useful

Comment: Thank @mark_h, yes, I want to verifying that a request to send an email was correctly raise. How do i code it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$mock = Mockery::mock('Swift_Mailer');
$this->app['mailer']->setSwiftMailer($mock);
$mock->shouldReceive('send')->once()
    ->andReturnUsing(function($msg) {
        $this->assertEquals('My subject', $msg->getSubject());
        $this->assertEquals('foo@bar.com', $msg->getTo());
        $this->assertContains('Some string', $msg->getBody());
    });
```

you can see this:
[Laravel unit testing emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222570/laravel-unit-testing-emails)

Comment: Thanks for response. With this code snipset, when run testcase, it have a error: "Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method send() from Mockery_0_Illuminate_Support_Testing_Fakes_MailFake should be called exactly 1 times but called 0 times."