# How to get messages sent with the `array` mail driver?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Starting from version 5.7 Laravel suggests to use the `array` driver for Mail during testing:

[image]

Unfortunately, [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail) tells nothing about this driver. According to [the source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Mail/Transport/ArrayTransport.php), the driver stores all the messages in memory without actually sending them. How to get the stored "sent" messages during unit testing (in order to check them)?

Comment: don't post code as image

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski The code is not a subject of the question. It is an illustration to show the change. Stack Overflow can't display code difference so I added it as a picture and made the picture be a link to the code.

Comment: ah, I see now. Fair enough

Comment: I don't know if you can get them but it seems you can assert them. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mocking#mail-fake Sorry I wasn't able to answer your question directly.

Comment: @Wreight Mail fake is not the best option as it can check only the messages sent through the facade. I know [3 ways](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/testing-if-email-was-sent-with-out-sending-it/replies/402801) to test email sending and I want to explore the `array` transport to know the 4th.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `app()->make('swift.transport')->driver()->messages()`. The return value is a collection of `Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage` objects.

An example of a full PHPUnit test:

```
public function testEmail()
{
    Mail::to('user@example.com')->send(new MyMail);

    $emails = app()->make('swift.transport')->driver()->messages();
    $this->assertCount(1, $emails);
    $this->assertEquals(['user@example.com'], array_keys($emails[0]->getTo()));
}
```

Comment: This does not work with Laravel 8. `Target class [swift.transport] does not exist.` You should use `app()->make('mailer')->getSwiftMailer()->getTransport()->messages()` instead.

Comment: @areed Thanks for the hint. I haven't been working with Laravel for a long time already so I can't check it and update my answer. Please post your answer that is suitable for Laravel 8.

Answer (score 9):

EDIT: With Laravel 9+, use:

```
$emails = app()->make('mailer')->getSymfonyTransport()->messages();
dd($emails);
```

Be sure your mail driver is set to `array` in your `.env` or `phpunit.xml` file.

With Laravel 7+ or if you get error `Target class [swift.transport] does not exist` use this to get the list of emails sent with the array driver:

```
$emails = app()->make('mailer')->getSwiftMailer()->getTransport()->messages();

$count = $emails->count();
$subject = $emails->first()->getSubject();
$to = $emails->first()->getTo();
$body = $emails->first()->getBody();
```

Comment: Also worth noting that while this is called the Array transport, `messages()` actually returns a Collection.

Comment: Correct. `array` is just the name of the driver meaning emails are stored in memory rather than actually sent.

Answer (score 3):

My custom assertion based on Finesse's answer.

```
protected function assertMailSentTo($user, $expected = 1)
{
    $messages = app('swift.transport')->messages();

    $filtered = $messages->filter(function ($message) use ($user) {
        return array_key_exists($user->email, $message->getTo());
    });

    $actual = $filtered->count();

    $this->assertTrue(
        $expected === $actual,
        "Sent {$actual} messages instead of {$expected}."
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete mail testing example for Laravel 9, 10. (Using the array driver)

```php
    public function it_can_track_sent_emails_and_content()
    {
        $email1 = 'john@example.com';
        $subject1 = 'Welcome to our App';
        $message1 = 'Thank you for joining our application!';
        $message2 = 'Contact us for support.';
        
        // send the message to array driver
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::raw($message1 . ' ' . $message2, function ($message) use ($email1, $subject1) {
            $message->to($email1)
                ->subject($subject1);
        });

        // get the emails
        $emails = $this->app->make('mailer')->getSymfonyTransport()->messages();

        // verify mail count
        $this->assertCount(1, $emails);

        // get first email
        /** @var \Illuminate\Mail\SentMessage $email */
        $email = $emails->first();

        $to = $email->getEnvelope()->getRecipients();

        $recipients = [];
        foreach ($to as $address) {
            $recipients[$address->getAddress()] = $address->getName();
        }

        // verify recipient by email
        $this->assertArrayHasKey($email1, $recipients);

        // verify the subject line
        $this->assertEquals($subject1, $email->getOriginalMessage()->getSubject());

        // verify mail content
        $this->assertStringContainsString($message1, $email->getOriginalMessage()->getBody()->toString());
        $this->assertStringContainsString($message2, $email->getOriginalMessage()->getBody()->toString());
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't you still need a `send` inside the raw callback?